# How to make screen move with the character in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-physics

I am a beginner in pygame and I'd like to develop a game simple game where the screen moves along with the character.

What is the best method to do so?

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to move the backround without moving the character so it looks like the character is moving.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it

Comment: @user13500822 I would also suggest you group together the entire screen, other than the main character. This would make your job a lot easier.

Comment: @user13500822 Can you post the code in your question or on github so we can help you better?